# How to count and do average for the result of aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to group by city and store, then get the latest record, then filter the result by price

the data example：

```
{"city_name" : "NY","store_name" : "xxx","price" : 150,"entry_time" : 1649792100000},
{"city_name" : "NY","store_name" : "xxx","price" : 120,"entry_time" : 1649792000000},
{"city_name" : "NY","store_name" : "yyy","price" : 220,"entry_time" : 1649792100000},
{"city_name" : "NY","store_name" : "yyy","price" : 120,"entry_time" : 1649792000000},
{"city_name" : "SF","store_name" : "xxx","price" : 250,"entry_time" : 1649792000000},
{"city_name" : "SF","store_name" : "xxx","price" : 200,"entry_time" : 1649792100000}
```

Below query is used to find out the latest record for every store and city combination. Then I use Java to calculate the store count of price<=100, the store count of 100<price<200 and the store count of price>=200 for every city. Then calculate the average of the price for every city.

I want to know can I achieve this directly in Elasticsearch query string?

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "city_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "store_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "store_name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "entry_time": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

expected output:

```
{
  "city_name": "NY",
  "low_price_count": 0
  "mid_price_count": 1
  "high_price_count": 1
  "average_price": 185
},
{
  "city_name": "SF",
  "low_price_count": 0
  "mid_price_count": 0
  "high_price_count": 1
  "average_price": 200
}
```

Comment: Can you share sample documents

Comment: @Amit, have added the example data

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `top_hits` and compute the counts in your Java application, you could simply use the [`range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) and let ES do it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "city_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "store_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "store_name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "entry_time": {
              "max": {
                "field": "entry_time"
              }
            },
            "price_ranges": {
              "range": {
                "field": "price",
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "to": 100
                  },
                  {
                    "from": 100,
                    "to": 200
                  },
                  {
                    "from": 200
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I put the range aggregation? I need to get the count for every city.

Comment: with this, it returns the count for every store and city combination. But I want to use the latest record in every store and city combination to get the store count for every city. You can check my output example. Is this doable in ES?

Comment: In your aggregation query it's not clear which document you get back with `top_hits` since you don't specify any sort clause, so by default you get the best scored document, but since you don't have any scoring query, it can any document. According to your description you should have `"sort": "entry_time:desc"` in your top_hits aggregation

Comment: Yes, I have updated the query. But I'm still not clear how to get the count I want directly in ES.

Comment: This is not correct. it counts for all records per city, not for the latest one per store. What I need is to get every store latest record per city, then filter the price.